# remove leading zeroes from timestamp %j%Y %H:%M

Tags: regex, r, date

My timestamp is in the form

```
0992006 09:00
```

I need to remove the leading zeros to get this form:

```
992006 9:00
```

Here's the code I'm using now, which doesn't remove leading zeros:

```
prediction$TIMESTAMP <- as.character(format(prediction$TIMESTAMP, '%j%Y %H:%M'))
```

Comment: You should probably drop the `as.character()`. All format functions I am familiar with return 'character' classed vectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
str1 <- "0992006 09:00"
gsub("(?<=^| )0+", "", str1, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "992006 9:00"
```

For situations like below, it could be:

```
str2 <- "0992006 00:00"
 gsub("(?<=^| )0", "", str2, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "992006 0:00"
```

#### Explanation

Here the idea is to use `look behind` `(?<=^| )0+` to match `0`s

if it occurs either at the beginning of the string
`(?<=^`

or `|`

if it follows after a space  `)0+`

and replace those matched `0s` by `""` in the second part of the `gsub` argument.

In the second string, the `hour` and `minutes` are all `0's`.  So, using the first `code` would result in:

```
 gsub("(?<=^| )0+", "", str2, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "992006 :00"
```

Here, it is unclear what the OP would accept as a result.  So, I thought, instead of removing the whole `0`s before the `:`, it would be better if one `0` was left. So, I replaced the multiple `0+` code to just one `0` and replace that by `""`.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain the "look-behind" regex formalism a bit. (I'm sometimes guilty of code-only regex answers, too, but I think the addition of conditional starting points would deserve some explication.)

Answer (score 8):

Simplest way is to create your own boundary that asserts either the start of the string or a space precedes.

```
gsub('(^| )0+', '\\1', '0992006 09:00')
# [1] "992006 9:00"
```

You could do the same making the replacement exempt using a trick. `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included.

```
gsub('(^| )\\K0+', '', '0992006 09:00', perl=T)
# [1] "992006 9:00"
```

Or you could use `sub` and match until the second set of leading zeros.

```
sub('^0+([0-9]+ )0+', '\\1', '0992006 09:00')
# [1] "992006 9:00"
```

And to cover all possibilities, if you know that you will ever have a format like `0992006 00:00`, simply remove the `+` quantifier from zero in the regular expression so it only removes the first leading zero.

Comment: Your first example surprised me (and still does). I wasn't sure how `"\\1"` got defined. I was accustomed to having it defined by the contents of the first set of paired parentheses but that doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: @BondedDust Say you have a capture group like this `(foo|bar)` this will capture either foo or bar and `\\1` returns the results of what is captured in the replacement. Well the way it works here is kind of the same, `(^| )` basically captures either the zero-width space at the start of the string `^` or a space character that precedes the leading zero so in the replacement `\\1` will return only the space character to its original position since `^` anchors the beginning of the string and there is no actual match. You can see the zero-width position here, http://regex101.com/r/aO6uJ0/1

Answer (score 7):

Here's another option using a lookbehind

```
gsub("(^0)|(?<=\\s)0", "", "0992006 09:00", perl = TRUE)
## [1] "992006 9:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sub`:

```
  sub("^[0]+", "", prediction$TIMESTAMP) 
[1] "992006 09:00"
```

Comment: I need to delete the leading zero from the time also. Can you show me how to do that using sub?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `stringr` without a regular expression, by using the substrings.

```
> library(stringr)
> str_c(str_sub(word(x, 1:2), 2), collapse = " ")
# [1] "992006 9:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more Perl regexes,

```
> gsub("(?<!:)\\b0+", "", "0992006 09:00", perl=T)
[1] "992006 9:00"
> gsub("(?<![\\d:])0+", "", "0992006 09:00", perl=T)
[1] "992006 9:00"
```